# Does Tortoise SVN allow search in repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In a project I cannot find one file. I suppose that file was deleted in some revision.

I know only the name of file. Is possible to find this file with the Tortoise SVN client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have terminal svn client you can do something like

```
svn log -r <last_revision_you_know_file_existed> <deleted file>
```

Or you can try the following (in linux):

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD -v | grep D | grep -v M | grep -v A | grep <filename>
```

This will print complete svn operations log of a project, starting from revision1, until HEAD.
Than you filter the (D)eleted files, not interested in (M)oved or (A)dded, and finally grepping for the "filename" in the set of (D)eleted files.

You can execute similar command in PowerShell (Winboze)

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD -v | where {$_ -match "^   D"}
```

to get a list of all deleted files, than use MSOffice2011 + search I guess :D

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

If you know the directory it was in, you can right-click on the directory, then choose "Tortoise SVN..." and then "Show log"

Once the dialog box displays, type the filename into the text box at the top of the window (with the magnifying glass next to it).  If it was deleted a long time ago, you may need to use the "Show All" or "Next 100" buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Good luck!

Comment: A very neat way to find deleted files, so +1. But I just wanted to clarify: knowing what folder is not required, because `Show Log` reveals *everything* under the selected folder. But that is both a blessing and a curse--it could show too much and take longer to load. So it is *better* if you know the target folder but not required.